# Protractor tests fail on IE when developer tools closed

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**Situation**

I'm trying to run some automated tests in Internet Explorer. They already run fine in Firefox, but for some reason, they will only run as expected in IE when I open up the developer tools shortly after the browser window opens.

Basically, these two tests are not compatible with each other while dev tools is closed:

```
it('logs in', () => {
    browser.get('/#/login');

    element(by.model('vm.credentials.username')).sendKeys('noaccounts@neocles.io');
    element(by.model('vm.credentials.password')).sendKeys('test1234');

    element(by.css('#sign-in')).click();

    expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#sign-in')).getAttribute('class')).toMatch(/\bloading\b/);

    expect(element(by.css('.account-list p:last-child')).getText()).toBe('AccountPage.NoAccountsForUser');
    expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#sign-in')).getAttribute('class')).not.toMatch(/\bloading\b/);
});

it('autoselects single account', () => {
    browser.get('/#/login');

    element(by.model('vm.credentials.username')).sendKeys('shopowner@neocles.io');
    element(by.model('vm.credentials.password')).sendKeys('test1234');

    element(by.css('#sign-in')).click();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('http://localhost:8000/#/');
});
```

**Expected behavior**

So in both tests it's doing a login action, which causes the Authorization header on subsequent requests to be set to a certain value. Then a list of accounts is fetched, that you have access to, and this list is based on the token that is sent through the Authorization header. For the first test, the list is empty, for the second, there should be one account.

**Actual behavior**

What happens is that in the second test, it seems to be doing requests to the server with the Authorization header that was set during the first test. Either that, or it is caching the XHR request in the first request and using that in the second. I can't tell for sure, because, as I said, it works when dev tools is open, so I can't verify that that is what is happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the ["*ensure clean session*"](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html#IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION) to `true` in your capabilities config:

> Capability that defines to clean or not browser cache before launching IE by IEDriverServer.

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: "internet explorer",
    ensureCleanSession: true
},
```